# Simplistic way to send data to another process (win)?

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, ipc, c++17

Suppose you are developing two application for the windows platform (A and B).

The platform/system is Windows (Windows 10 if that matters)

How can you send some piece of information to B from A if you are only allowed to work at the c++ language level (that is: including the standard libraries and STL) ? This rules out any third party libraries.

I'm trying to avoid the system API as it usually involves a healthy amount of c-like programming (and therefore is not suited for my purpose).

In this particular scenario both processes are running continuously and the sending happens due to some outside event (if it matters) - so some kind of sync is probably needed.

Possible solutions under consideration:

1. Using files, via `std::ofstream` and `std::ifstream` could be a possible solution (albeit a crude one) ? - but how can sync'ing be achieved then ?
2. Even redirecting STDOUT to STDIN could be fine - especially if there is some simple way to set this up (eg. one-liner on command line to start - [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) could be a possibility if needed)

Comment: As mentioned last time, the c++ standard library doesn't have any notion about IPC. Your question is too broad again.

Comment: File is really the only way if you want to avoid the Windows API, and then without any synchronization. Otherwise, named pipes would probably be simplest.

Comment: And unless you use third-part libraries (why not?) you're never getting out of doing "C-like programming" if you want to do anything not part of standard C++. Unless this is for a learning exercise, I really recommend you use libraries. No need to reinvent the wheel (and probably badly).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ when you answer 'No', then why is that too broad ?  im not asking for possible solutions - im asking for just one solution that will work

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it is indeed for a sort of learning exercise - which is why im trying to scrape away as much as possible.

Comment: If you use files, cant you include a header when you write to the file that includes time and some more info you could use for syncing?

Comment: Did no one mention @darune can use sockets as a form of IPC? It's a viable and fairly simple solution since you most likely won't be dealing with multiple threads or multiple sockets. It will be simple communication between server and client.

Comment: @styphNate a solution with files i think could be possible - perhaps creating a second file when the data file has been created, but im considering if there is an even simpler way (since this also involves scanning in some way...)

Comment: Really doubt you will find a simpler solution than files

Comment: @Nina As far as I am aware, sockets API are not part of standard C++, and would require some sort of OS-based library.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ check out the answer -still think it is impossible ?

Answer (score 1):

A solution involving transfer via a datafile (this uses `std::filesystem::rename` as a way of sync'ing or you could say avoid it):

**a.exe (writer)**

```
#include <filesystem>

auto tmpfile = std::filesystem::temp_directory_path() / "some_uuid.txt";
auto datafile = std::filesystem::temp_directory_path() / "data.txt";
std::ofstream(tmpfile) << "hello" << std::endl;

std::filesystem::rename(tmpfile, datafile);
```

**b.exe (reader)**

```
auto datafile = std::filesystem::temp_directory_path() / "data.txt";
while (!std::filesystem::exists(datafile)) {
  ;//we have nothing else to do ?
}
std::ifstream input(data);
//read input etc.
```